# Mantener efecto hover al hacer click en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo cuatro cuadros que son `inputs` que cada uno es una opción clicable. Cuando le hago clic sale un reborde amarillo en el que hecho clic. Además le he añadido por javascript que según paso por los distintos cuadros se me opacitan los tres menos en el que estoy encima.

```js
    $( "#depilacionCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","0.3")
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    $( "#depilacionCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    
    $( "#liftingCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","0.3")
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    $( "#liftingCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    
    $( "#lipoCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","0.3")
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    $( "#lipoCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    
    $( "#inkCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","0.3")
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
    
    $( "#inkCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","1");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
    });
```

```css
    .checkeable input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    .checkeable input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable input:checked  + img {
        border-color: #FFEB3B;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .checkeable2 input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable2 img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    .checkeable2 input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable2 input:checked  + img {
        border-color: #FFEB3B;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
        <label class="checkeable">
        <input type="radio" value="laser" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
         <img src="images/menu/laser.svg" alt="" id="depilacionCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#aa0bb6;">
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
         <label class="checkeable">
         <input type="radio" value="lifting" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
         <img src="images/menu/lift.svg" alt="" id="liftingCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#e03997;">
           </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
            <label class="checkeable">
            <input type="radio" value="lipo" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
            <img src="images/menu/lipoHifu.svg" alt="" id="lipoCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#199cea;">
            </label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
            <label class="checkeable">
            <input type="radio" value="ink" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
            <img src="images/menu/tatto.svg" alt="" id="inkCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#00d278;">
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Lo que necesito es que una vez haga clic en una opción, además de que salga el borde amarillo, los otros 3 inputs se tornen mas opacos.

Además estoy seguro de que esto que estoy haciendo se puede hacer de una forma más simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo puedes hacer colocando una variable bandera y una variable donde guardes la opción seleccionada, de modo que una vez seleccionada una opción ya no cambie el hover de las demás opciones.

También para hacer mas ligero el código puedes tener una función que opaque todos los inputs menos el seleccionado, ademas de otra para cuando ya tengas una opción seleccionada.

El código funcionando queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
var ban=0; //indica si ya se ha seleccionado un input
var elegido="";
$("#depilacionCuadro").click(function() {
  ban=1;
  elegido='#depilacionCuadro';
  opacar();
});
$("#liftingCuadro").click(function() {
  ban=1;
  elegido='#liftingCuadro';
  opacar();
});
$("#lipoCuadro").click(function() {
  ban=1;
  elegido='#lipoCuadro';
  opacar();
});
$("#inkCuadro").click(function() {
  ban=1;
  elegido='#inkCuadro';
  opacar();
});

$( "#depilacionCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      opacar2("0.3","#depilacionCuadro");
    });
    $( "#depilacionCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      opacar();
    });
    $( "#liftingCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      opacar2("0.3","#liftingCuadro");
    });
    $( "#liftingCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      opacar();
    });
    $( "#lipoCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      opacar2("0.3","#lipoCuadro");
    });
    $( "#lipoCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      opacar();
    });
    $( "#inkCuadro" ).mouseenter(function() {
      opacar2("0.3","#inkCuadro");
    });
    $( "#inkCuadro" ).mouseleave(function() {
      opacar();
    });
    
function opacar(){
  if(ban==0){
    por="1";
  }else{
    por="0.3";
  }
  $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
  $(elegido).css("opacity",1);
}
function opacar2(por,esteno){
  $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#inkCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#liftingCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#depilacionCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity",por);
      $('#lipoCuadro').css("all 0.3s ease-in-out");
      $(esteno).css("opacity",1);
      $(elegido).css("opacity",1);
}
```

```css
.checkeable input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    .checkeable input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable input:checked  + img {
        border-color: #FFEB3B;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .checkeable2 input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable2 img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    .checkeable2 input {
        display: none;
    }
    .checkeable2 input:checked  + img {
        border-color: #FFEB3B;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
        <label class="checkeable">
        <input type="radio" value="laser" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
         <img src="images/menu/laser.svg" alt="" id="depilacionCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#aa0bb6;">
        </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
         <label class="checkeable">
         <input type="radio" value="lifting" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
         <img src="images/menu/lift.svg" alt="" id="liftingCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#e03997;">
           </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
            <label class="checkeable">
            <input type="radio" value="lipo" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
            <img src="images/menu/lipoHifu.svg" alt="" id="lipoCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#199cea;">
            </label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-3" style="padding:3px;">
            <label class="checkeable">
            <input type="radio" value="ink" class="servicip" name="servicio" id="servicio"/>
            <img src="images/menu/tatto.svg" alt="" id="inkCuadro" class="imgOptions" style="background:#00d278;">
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Lo que pasa que si una vez marcada una (funciona bien) pero si vas a elegir otras siguen opacitadas y incluso si la marcas se queda opacitada @the-braker

Comment: @Miguel ¿quieres que las opciones opacadas se puedan seguir seleccionando luego de hacer click? ¿que mas necesitas?

Comment: Perdón si no lo explico 100% bien ;). Ahora esta correcto, pero una vez elegida una opción se puede cambiar de opinión, entonces tiene que hacer bien el hover. Es decir se vea con `opacity:1` y si selecciono otra se vea esa marcada y las otras no, espero explicarme bien

Comment: @Miguel, creo que ya esta como lo necesitas.

Comment: perdona @the-braker  esta impresionante, pero falto algo que no lo diria bien. Si tengo una opción marcada las otras tres están opacitadas, si quiero seleccionar otra al pasar por encima de ella tendria que volver con el hover a opacity:1. Lo otro de que se queden marcadas esta perfectisimo, gracias.

Comment: @Miguel, esta bien dame un momento.

Comment: @Miguel, creo que ya esta por fin, me costo un poco.

Comment: BUAH!!! eres un crack @the-breaker. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda ;)

Comment: @Miguel, de nada, que tengas buen día.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la misma forma que has hecho cuando entra el mouse, lo diferente es que cuando haga click le asigne la opacidad a los demas mediante el css, como hiciste en esta linea:

```
$('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
```

Comment: No se muy bien como hacer eso en CSS gracias por tu respuesta @Artudoxo

Comment: Mira agregas a la etiqueta que es clickeable `onclick="tufuncion()"` lo que hará que cuando le des click ejecute la función, bien, en tu js crearas la función que asignara la opacidad como mencione antes, eso debería ser suficiente y así lo harías con los demás clickeables.

Comment: Lo probe de este modo pero no funciona: 
 `$( "#depilacionCuadro" ).click(function() {
    $('#liftingCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
    $('#lipoCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
    $('#inkCuadro').css("opacity","0.3");
  });`

Comment: También puedes usar `onfocus` [documentación aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

Comment: tal que así: `$( "#depilacionCuadro" ).onfocus(function() {`pero cree una función nueva además de la que tengo con la de `mouseneter` y `mouseleave`, es correcto así?

Comment: Por ejemplo:
`<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
</form>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);
x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction, true);

function myFocusFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 
}

function myBlurFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = ""; 
}
</script>`

Comment: Debería funcionar.

Comment: Lo que tu me pusiste o lo que te puse? si es lo que yo puse, puede ser que entre en conflicto con el otro javascript??

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de las 2 maneras.